# How is this gradient derived?

Tags: optimization, matrix, gradient-descent, matrix-decomposition

I am reading this paper, http://math.ucla.edu/~dakuang/pub/sdm0125.pdf, and came across this function, $f(x) = ||A-H^TH||_F^2$.  Later, the authors take the gradient of this function, $\nabla f$, but do not specify which variable they are taking this gradient with respect to (I assume it is $x$).  They later present a closed form for this gradient: $\nabla f(x) = vec(4(HH^T-A)H)$, where $vec(\cdot)$ is the vectorization operation by column.

How was this closed form derived?  $x$ appears nowhere and I'm not sure how to begin computing it.

Comment: HINT: Think about gradient with respect to $H$ and use matrix differentiation formula from the [cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) Eq. 84-88 and a few preceding ones